# VBA code to select from HTML Drop Down menu

Tags: vba, excel

I am starting out on trying my hand at writing VBA code and having issues selecting items from a drop down list.  It is a dynamic drop down box where by default, it is "None", once a selection is made in the first box, another box opens using the same data-field = "taxonomy_id", with new parameters to choose.

The HTML code for the drop down:

```
<select class="select select-custom" data-field="taxonomy_id">
            <option value="">
                    None
            </option>

                <optgroup label="Select a category">
                    <option value="1">Accessories</option>
                    <option value="66">Art &amp; Collectibles</option>
                    <option value="132">Bags &amp; Purses</option>
                    <option value="199">Bath &amp; Beauty</option>
                    <option value="323">Books, Movies &amp; Music</option>
                    <option value="374">Clothing</option>
                    <option value="562">Craft Supplies &amp; Tools</option>
                    <option value="825">Electronics &amp; Accessories</option>
                    <option value="891">Home &amp; Living</option>
                    <option value="1179">Jewelry</option>
                    <option value="1250" selected="">Paper &amp; Party Supplies</option>
                    <option value="1351">Pet Supplies</option>
                    <option value="1429">Shoes</option>
                    <option value="1552">Toys &amp; Games</option>
                    <option value="1633">Weddings</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
```

The code I have used to select "Paper & Party Supplies" is:

```
IE.document.all("taxonomy_id").Value = "1250"
```

The code I use above fails to select the item in the initial drop down box.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an URL to go with this?

Answer (score 0):

It is always a tough job to provide any solution hypothetically. However,give it a go. It should select `Paper & Party Supplies` from the dropdown option:

```
Sub Select_Item()
    Dim post As Object, elem As Object

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "webpage_link"  ''Try with your URL
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        ''If the content of that page generates dynamically, make sure to put here some delay

        Set post = .document.querySelector("select[data-field='taxonomy_id']")
        For Each elem In post.getElementsByTagName("option")
             If InStr(elem.Value, "1250") > 0 Then elem.Selected = True: Exit For
         Next elem
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try the script? What's the feedback?